# Docker building issue: Error checking context: can't stat

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I am running docker file on my repository but unknown issue was come up.
I wrote docker build . to the terminal but it said error checking context:

```
can't stat '/media/dev/Data/Project/.../src'
```

I'm not sure what the reason is and how to get out of this risk.
Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had a similar issue until recently . On 18.04, Ubuntu installs Docker via Snap.

By default, SNAP packages are not allowed to access /media, or any other / root folder. The SNAP sandbox will deny access unless you have explicitly granted access to removable-media. ( /mnt or /media )

To grant docker access to removable-media:

```
sudo snap connect docker:removable-media
```

Alternatively, move your project into your /home/user directory and try building from there.

Comment: What if this is not snap related?

Answer (score -1):

Presumably /media/dev/Data/Project/.../src is docker context path. This error happens to me when one the directories in the context path does not have execute/search or 'x' permission for the user running docker build.

Comment: So how did you figure it out?

Comment: I don't understand what the solution is.
Could you please more specify?

Comment: This is not a solution, it's a statement of fact.