# Docker: user suddently got permission denied, while everything was working fine 1 day ago

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, permissions

I'm on `Ubuntu 22.04 64bit` with `Docker version 20.10.21, build 20.10.21-0ubuntu1~22.04.3` and `Docker Compose version v2.15.1`

I'm using `Docker` with `docker-compose` to host my RoR app, with some custom script for deployment.

Basically, when I'm pushing to a branch, it triggers some stuff to build the image, remove old image, restart the services, etc.

Everything was working pretty fine, using it almost everyday.

Then suddently I had a deploy failure, with the following message :

```
cannot create user data directory: /home/web/snap/docker/2915: Permission denied
```

Logged with SSH to my server, and tried to run basic docker commands to test it. And I had the same issue : permission denied on that directory.
Tried to run Docker using `sudo` and this time it worked.

I am wondering what happened, and how the rights could suddently change, knowing I did not do any settings on my server.

I tried to put back rights to my user, using commands like

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
newgrp docker
```

Group was already existing, user already had correct privileges.
Also tried `chown` and even `chmod 777` for test purposes,
Also tried `snap disable docker` and `snap enable docker`.
Also tried to uninstall/reinstall docker using snap.
Nothing helped.

I read that actually using `snap` to install `Docker` was not recommended and could lead to permission issues.
So, I uninstalled it, and installed it again this time using `apt`, and now it worked fine, the permission of my user was correct, could use docker without `sudo`.

My question is :
How can the rights of a user suddently change ?

Comment: I've seen some other reports that permissions act funny with the Ubuntu "snap" system; for example [Docker - mkdir read-only file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52526219/docker-mkdir-read-only-file-system) or [Docker building issue: Error checking context: can't stat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59662154/docker-building-issue-error-checking-context-cant-stat).  Does it work better to install Docker using APT and not snap?

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, from my experience and what I've read, it's better to use APT